# Match Regex to a new line that has no characters preceding it

Tags: regex

```
example text

example text
```

I was wondering if there was a way to match the line break in the middle of these two bits of text.

I was using \n but it would match at the end of "example text" and in the blank line

I am using this in a text to speech program called Voicedream to say out loud that it has progressed to a new line.

Comment: That works perfectly. Thanks for replying so quickly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you only match a newline that is preceded with another newline.

Use a positive lookbehind `(?<=\n)`:

```
(?<=\n)\n
^^^^^^^
```